# Possible to get b without calling `test`?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently thinking about implementing a virtual machine inside of node.js that wraps up other apps. For that I am going to override some basics but there is one point I am not sure of.

```
var A = (function() {
    var b = 1;

    var A = function() {};
    A.prototype.test = function() { // Can't touch this
        return b;
    };
    A.prototype.foo = function(callback) {
        callback();
    };
    return A;
})();

// Objective: Get b without touching `test` in any way
```

Is this possible in any way? By injecting prototypes or using call(), apply(), bind() or similar? Any other sort of reflection?

Comment: Looks like you'll eat your cookie yourself ;-)

Comment: Indeed, A.test() should return b as written, unless I misunderstand you....

Comment: Can't do it... now my cookie!

Comment: He said without "touching" test which I assumed meant you can't change the code, not that you can't call it, but maybe I am wrong...

Comment: @Jonah: Check out the title. ;)

Comment: @sillylittleme, ah, ok, answer deleted.  In that case, I don't see any way to do it.

Comment: So am I assuming that `A.prototype.test` does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Without using `test`? Use a different `function`:

```
var A = (function() {
    var b = 1;

    // ...    

    A.prototype.foo = function () {
        return b;
    };
    return A;
})();

console.log(new A().foo());
```

Otherwise, no. The snippet is of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) and *only being able to reach local variables through functions defined in the same scope* is how they work.

Comment: Thank you already. If it's actually not possible this will do me a favour. Things I've tried till now: Creating A.prototype.foo outside of the closure and calling, applying, bindung it against A and new A(). This does not work, as expected. I just ask myself if there is some other nasty injection mechanism because that would be a real risk for security in my app otherwise :)

Comment: @dcode It might be possible through a native extension of the engine. A [Node.js Addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), perhaps. There are existing modules that seem like they're kind of verging on that capability (only guessing, though), like [`contextify`](https://npmjs.org/package/contextify).

Comment: You are right, that might be possible. I will prevent loading native modules. I just hope there is really no other way :)